# Why $|e^{itx}| = 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I'm studying some demonstrations of properties of characteristic function in which  I have  to use that $|e^{itx}| = 1$ but I don't understand it at all. Could you give a clue to demonstrate it?

Comment: ... because $\cos (tx)^2+\sin(tx)^2=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key property of the exponential map is

$$e^ze^{z^\prime} = e^{z+z^\prime}$$

This can be proven using [Cauchy product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Based on that, you get for $y \in \mathbb R$

$$\vert e^{iy}\vert^2= e^{iy} \overline{e^{iy}}=e^{iy}e^{-iy}=e^{iy-iy}=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much to you and all who answered!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$e^{itx}=\cos(tx)+i\sin(tx)$$